# 9 months old baby wakes up 8-10 times per night

Tags: sleep, nightwaking

From birth to 4 months, my baby slept very well, up to 12 hours without waking up, but after that, she wakes up several times per night, and last 2 months she wakes up about 8-10 times at night, is it normal? What can I do?

Comment: What ended up happening. This sounded so much like my baby I had to double check I didn't make this post half asleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is so incredibly common.  We had this with both of our children.  We used the Dr. Ferber method successfully.  Briefly: Soothing yourself back to sleep is a skill babies must learn.  You want them to know you are there for them while also giving them the opportunity to self-soothe.

To teach this, the "Ferber method" is to put them to bed while they are awake instead of after they fall asleep.  WHen they start to fuss, go in and let them know you are there and make sure they are okay, but dont comfort them physically, then leave.  As they continue fussing, go in after increasing time intervals: 1 minute between visits,, then 2 minutes, then 3-5 minutes, etc.  The book has a recommended schedule.

Many new parents find it very difficult to so this because the child will cry when they leave.  The first few nights are hard but if you stick to it the child learns in only a few days.

Babycenter summary:
https://www.babycenter.com/0_the-ferber-method-demystified_7755.bc

The book:
http://www.barnesandnoble.com/mobile/w/solve-your-childs-sleep-problems-richard-ferber/1115231359